# How to use comboBox to change color of a label?

Tags: list, colors, combobox

I'm new to C# and it's for a class. My friend has the exact same code and it works for him. Essentially, comboBox is coded to have every color in it to choose from. Clicking a color in the comboBox will assign that color to the label. Simple as that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NWnP.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmZW6.png)

I tried restarting the program but it didn't work. Copied my friend letter for letter.

Comment: Please share code as text and not as screenshot. [ask]